# Why is my build.gradle file diffrent from documentation

Tags: kotlin, gradle, plugins, build.gradle, dsl

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
id 'kotlin-android-extensions'

}


dependencies {

def lifecycle_version = "2.4.0-alpha02"
def room_version = "2.3.0"

implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.0")
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")


}
```

Some resources using apply plugin: 'example' or id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.5.21"
but mine is id 'example' why it's diffrent

Comment: build.gradle can be written in groovy or kotlin, as well differently for java so it will differ in all the three cases

Comment: There are different ways to specify plugins. `apply plugin: 'example'` is the [legacy method](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:old_plugin_application); modern scripts typically use  the `plugins {}` block.